# How to add yAxis2 to qCustomplot?

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

I don't know how to add yAxis2 to a qcustomplot. The way i am using qcustomplot, I don't specify xAxis or yAxis. But i need to plot another graph on yAxis2. I will appreciate any inputs.

```
    ui->widget->addGraph();
    ui->widget->graph()->setData(xVal,yVal);

    ui->widget->setInteractions(QCP::iRangeDrag | QCP::iRangeZoom | QCP::iSelectAxes |
                                 QCP::iSelectLegend | QCP::iSelectPlottables);

     ui->widget->graph()->setName(QString::number(yVal[0]));
    ui->widget->legend->setVisible(true);
     QFont legendFont = font();
    legendFont.setPointSize(10);
    ui->widget->legend->setFont(legendFont);
    ui->widget->legend->setSelectedFont(legendFont);
    ui->widget->rescaleAxes();
    ui->widget->replot();
```

Comment: This is how its done.. didn't read the documentation. Might be useful for other folks
        ui->widget->yAxis2->setVisible(true);
        ui->widget->xAxis2->setVisible(true);
        ui->widget->yAxis2->scaleRange(-1,1);
        ui->widget->addGraph(ui->widget->xAxis2,ui->widget->yAxis2);
        ui->widget->graph(1)->setData(xVal,yVal);

Answer (score 0):

```
    ui->widget->yAxis2->setVisible(true);
    ui->widget->xAxis2->setVisible(true);
    ui->widget->yAxis2->scaleRange(-1,1);
    ui->widget->addGraph(ui->widget->xAxis2,ui->widget->yAxis2);
    ui->widget->graph(1)->setData(xVal,yVal);
```